# How can I show an Image in UI?

Tags: python

I want to show an Image in my UI

[image]

I found the [same question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/155135/how-to-display-an-image-in-blender-ui-with-python) here but It didn't work for me

I haven't any error but It didn't show an Image in UI

```
import bpy
 
 
class ADDONNAME_PT_main_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Main Panel"
    bl_idname = "ADDONNAME_PT_main_panel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "New Tab"
 
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
 
        obj = context.object
        

        row = layout.row()
        image = bpy.data.images.load("C:/Users/Kamali/Desktop/Test.png")

        row.template_ID_preview(image, "image", open="image.open")
        row.operator("addonname.myop_operator")
        row = layout.row()
        

            
            
 
 
class ADDONNAME_OT_my_op(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Operator"
    bl_idname = "addonname.myop_operator"
    
    
    def execute(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
          
classes = [ADDONNAME_PT_main_panel, ADDONNAME_OT_my_op]
 
 
def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls) 
       
 
def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
        del bpy.types.Scene.my_tool

 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

but I can't see any texture in my panel?

[image]

I'm sure that my image loaded correctly

[image]

Comment: There are several ways of displaying an image, Another way: `row.template_ID_preview(data, "image", open="image.open")`. Please be more specific what *exactly* does not work.

Comment: @brockmann your solution didn't work for me: ```row.template_ID_preview(bpy.data, "image", open = "C:/Users/Kamali/Desktop/Test.png")```

Comment: How to use it: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html?highlight=template_id_preview#bpy.types.UILayout.template_ID_preview

Comment: Surely trying to load an image in a draw method is spitting errors constantly to console?  Recommend double checking  before chirping _"it doesn't work"_   The open argument is an operator not a filepath.  `bpy.data` has no property "image"

Comment: @batFINGER I tried to use @brockmann script but I had an error ```NameError: name 'data' is not defined ``` so I changed it to ```bpy.data```. I don't know what is data in his code.I tried pass an Image but didn't work!

Comment: Just like any prop, `foo.bar`  use `row.template_ID_preview(foo, "bar")` where the property "bar" of object `foo`  is an image.

Comment: @batFINGER I updated my code and I used an Image it runs without any errors but there isn't any image in my panel

Comment: For example an image texture node has an "image" property that is type `bpy.types.Image`.

Comment: There are errors. `ui_template_id: pointer property not found: Image.image`  The object is an image which has no property "image" hence the error.  Are you aware of how `getattr(foo, "bar")` works. Also See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6173/where-does-console-output-go  Finally loading an image in a draw method is not a good idea, this is why your "loaded image" image above is number 67... and counting.