# Blender Python | How to make an Enumerator with images preview?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I've seen in plenty of add-ons how they draw in the Gui an enumerator with small preview images (ex. Easy PBR material preview, Botaniq asset selector, etc.). I tried to "reverse engineer" it, but to be honest I can't even start to comprehend how it is done nor I could find a tutorial or an explanation online. may someone explain how can I code that?

Comment: You may want to start by looking at the ui_previews_dynamic_enum.py template available in blender (keep in mind this template only previews .png files based on line 48 `if fn.lower().endswith(".png"):`).

Comment: Oh, I see, I'll check it out. Thanks

Comment: This is answered here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/155135/how-to-display-an-image-in-blender-ui-with-python